# Java println() Printing chars

Tags: java

I'm trying to print two chars with

```
System.out.println(char1 + char2);
```

but it's adding the integer values together and printing the sum...

How do I print the chars themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dereference a char, IE tostring, but you can let the java know how to interpret your intentions:

```
System.out.println(char1 + "" +char2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
System.out.println(Character.toString(char1) + Character.toString(char2));
```

If your variables are `chars`

Try:

```
System.out.println(char1.toString() + char2.toString());
```

If they are [java.lang.Characters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 System.out.println(char1+""+char2);
```