# How to read 2 bytes symbols in java into short?

Tags: java, char, short

So f.e. i have a file ala.xs that contains: "sąłs" and i would like to read those symbols from this file and then put them into the table of shorts and then printf them on stdout. I am having some trouble with this becouse I have to read them as single chars and then join this chars into shorts.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        short [] words = new short[10];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
            words[i] = 0;
        Reader reading = new FileReader("ala.xs");
        short character;
        int i = 0;
        while ((character = (short) reading.read()) != -1) {
            words[i] = character;
            System.out.println(words[i]);
            i++;
        }
        reading.close();
    }
}
```

I tried to printf them like `System.out.println((char)words[i]);` but this is just stupid. I had this same task to do in C and in C i just had to printf them as %c and stdout joined them automaticly (that is my theory)

Comment: If you want to say 2 bytes into a short integer please say it so. 'B' is not clear.

Comment: The real question should be why are you trying to out text into integers. What are trying to achieve? What is the language and the encoding of the input file?

Comment: UTF-8 I am trying to print on Stdout all the words that are in the file. I don't understand what you mean by trying to out text into integers

Comment: In C strings are just sequences of characters and C doesn't care about encodings. In other languages like Java Strings are not just characters and internally use UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: When you say word do you mean words in the text? Like "house", "car"?

Comment: Are you sure you should be reading this as text file, and not as a binary file (e.g. using a `FileInputStream`)?

Comment: Yeah, i tried reading it as FileInputStream but it doesn't change anything

Comment: The last question you posted on this was somewhat different. Did you delete that question?

Comment: Are you using the term “words” to mean language elements, like the four words “I” “have” “a” “file”?  Or are you using “words” in the assembly language sense, where a word is a two-byte value, a dword is four bytes, etc.?

Comment: Words as a characters like 'a' 'b' 'c' and the two bytes 'ą' 'ł' 'ć'

Comment: characters and words are different concepts. Mixing the terms introduces confusions. You should use characters and clarify when you expect multi-byte characters.

Comment: "So f.e. i have a file ala.xs that contains: "sąłs" and i would like to read those symbols from this file and then put them into the table of shorts and then printf them on stdout." Exactly what do you think should be the result for this input, and why? Exactly how many bytes do you think are in the file, and why? (Did you try to check? How?) What happens when you try using your existing code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen? What is a `.xs` file (e.g., how did you create it)?

Comment: Well this file was created by my program written in C that is a simple compressor. It compresses files like .txt .mp4 e.t.c. (generally all files), and it produces this file .xs that contains all information about the compressed file and information needed to decompress it. In java i wanted to write a decompressor for this file and i am having difficulty with chars, couse in C the compiler or i don't know what (maybe god) split the characters like ą into two characters and then when u printed those two characters in the good order it joined it again into ą. And i can't seem to do this in java

Comment: I will probably post another question with more code and explanation on what is the problem, sorry for all the trouble and thanks a lot 4 your help. What should i do with this question then?

Comment: Compression has certainly nothing at all to do with characters or words. You should probably have stated your [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions) and not your *steps*. You can correct that in your new question

Answer (score 1):

From my comment above, it follows that the proper container for your codes is `int[]`. Knowing that your encoding is UTF-8, the following should give you what you want

```
public static int[] fileToCodepointArray(Path p) throws IOException {
    byte[] fileContents = Files.readAllBytes(p);
    return new String(fileContents, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).codePoints().
        toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to read all the characters of the input file then instead of using the array of `short` directly concatenate the characters into a String. Using a StringBuilder is more efficient than concatenating directly to a String because Strings in Java are immutable.

It should be something like this:

```java
char character;
StringBuilder text;
while ((character = (char) reading.read()) != -1) {
   text.append(character);
}
String words=text.toString();
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that i have to use this char table

Comment: Why? That's what I'm trying to understand. Are you using the array later for something else?

Comment: @aled The last question on this was printing the character codes as numbers. That question was deleted

Comment: @aled Yes this is just a part of a bigger project, I need to have characters in the table

Comment: Than have an array of `char`, not `short`. If at some point need a string you can use `StringBuilder.append(charArray)` or to print each character use `Character.toString(c)` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7870173/721855

Comment: As I explained in your previous question, before you deleted it without explanation, you need to be careful about the character encoding. Just using the default encoding might not work

Comment: Unicode (which is what you're dealing with) is unfortunately not that simple. Firstly, not only can the *codepoints* in your text file exceed the capacity of a 16 bit numeric type such as `char` or `short` but if you were to maintain your original plan for `short[]` then some values might be negative, depending on what is in the text file